# import pymongo_spark doesn't work when executing with spark-commit

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark

I am running into problem running my script with spark-submit. The main script won't even run because `import pymongo_spark` returns `ImportError: No module named pymongo_spark`

I checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391840/getting-spark-python-and-mongodb-to-work-together) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485851/issues-setting-up-apache-spark-with-mongo-hadoop-connector) to try to figure out the issue, but so far there's no result.

My setup:

`$HADOOP_HOME` is set to `/usr/local/cellar/hadoop/2.7.1` where my hadoop files are

`$SPARK_HOME` is set to `/usr/local/cellar/apache_spark/1.5.2`

I also followed those threads and guide online as close as possible to get

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python:$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python/build:$PYTHONPATH

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

then I used this piece of code to test in the first thread I linked

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import pymongo_spark

pymongo_spark.activate()

def main():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName('pyspark test')
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then in the terminal, I did:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --jars $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/mongo-hadoop-r1.4.2-1.4.2.jar --driver-class-path $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/mongo-hadoop-r1.4.2-1.4.2.jar --master local[4] ~/Documents/pysparktest.py
```

Where `mongo-hadoop-r1.4.2-1.4.2.jar` is the jar I built following [this guide](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop#building)

I'm definitely missing things, but I'm not sure where/what I'm missing. I'm running everything locally on Mac OSX El Capitan. Almost sure this doesn't matter, but just wanna add it in.

EDIT:

I also used another jar file `mongo-hadoop-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, the same problem remains

my command:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --jars $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/mongo-hadoop-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --driver-class-path $HADOOP_HOME/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/mongo-hadoop-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --master local[4] ~/Documents/pysparktest.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pymongo_spark` is available only on `mongo-hadoop` 1.5 so it won't work with `mongo-hadoop` 1.4. To make it available you have to add directory with Python package to the `PYTHONPATH` as well. If you've built package by yourself it is located in [`spark/src/main/python/`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/spark/src/main/python).

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$MONGO_SPARK_SRC/src/main/python
```

where `MONGO_SPARK_SRC` is a directory with Spark Connector source.

See also [Getting Spark, Python, and MongoDB to work together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391840/1560062)

Comment: So that's why..... I got it to work (at least the import error doesn't show up now). thanks a lot!